# How can I enable access to local network devices while connected to VPN through GUI Network Manager in Ubuntu 19.10?

Tags: networking, network-manager, vpn, openvpn

I added an OpenVPN profile to Ubuntu (19.10) Network Manager via GUI. Connecting to and using internet through this VPN works fine (via IP or domain name, IP is 10.137.10.60), but I can't access local network devices of course. In my case, I am trying to mount an SMB share. How can I accomplish allowing connections to this SMB share to get out of the machine while the VPN is enabled? I have not done any other config other than setting up the VPN profile. All settings in network manager under the VPN profile are still set to whatever the defaults are.

`netstat -nr` while connected to VPN

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
0.0.0.0         10.15.0.1       0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 tun0
0.0.0.0         10.137.85.1     0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 ens160
10.15.0.0       0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U         0 0          0 tun0
10.137.85.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 ens160
10.137.85.1     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH        0 0          0 ens160
108.182.226.219 10.137.85.1     255.255.255.255 UGH       0 0          0 ens160
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U         0 0          0 ens160
```

`netstat -nr` while DISCONNECTED from VPN

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
0.0.0.0         10.137.85.1     0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 ens160
10.137.85.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 ens160
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U         0 0          0 ens160
```

Comment: Probably some network routes are not configured properly.

Comment: Didn't configure any routes at all, just whatever it would have by default. Where and what would I make this route to allow all traffic to go through VPN except for connection to this one SMB share?

Comment: Please, [edit] your question and add information about: (1) How do you connect to the SMB share? Are you using IP address or hostname? What is the IP address of the SMB server? (2) `netstat -nr` output when VPN is *disconnected* and again when VPN is *connected*.

Comment: Added netstat outputs to question.

Comment: The net mask for your 10.137 network is currently 255.255.255.0 . Can you change it to 255.255.0.0 and try again? Your router and SMB server should be updated also.

Answer (score 2):

It really depends on what you are trying to achieve. For example, if you are only trying to use certain resources through the VPN you can try cheacking this box

[image]

If you are trying to tunnel all traffic and you don't control the other end point, you should still be able to access local resources via their IP (assuming that the VPN you are connecting to does not use the same IP range).

For example, I have OpenVPN setup on my PFSense. It shunts VPN Users to a 10.x.x.x network, while most home networks start with 192 or 172. This means that there is no confusion about which machine I am trying to access if I ping 192.168.1.111.

Hopefully this helps clear things up. As for your specific samba question you can hit

`ctrl + l` while in Nautilus (Files app) to bring up the bar. You can then type `smb://some.ip/sharename` and connect that way

Comment: So to make sure nothing else is affecting SMB working, I connected to the share and tested with VPN disabled. Everything works fine.

I want to have all traffic go through the VPN except for the connection to this one SMB share. I enable the VPN, internet works fine, but connection to SMB no longer works. Starts working fine again if I disconnect VPN.

I tried checking the box you suggested which makes internet stop working when connected to the VPN, and the SMB share still doesn't connect. I don't control VPN endpoint, so not sure what subnet it is on. SMB share subnet is 10.139.40.0/24.

Comment: and you tried connecting via IP to the samba share? What are you using to test? Have you tried mounting the smb share via the terminal and then navigating the directory from the terminal?

Comment: Yes tried via IP and domain name. I am testing by just trying to connect to the share via GUI. As soon as I disconnect VPN, I am able to hit connect button again and it works. I also cannot ping the share server while connected but I can while disconnected.

Comment: I have been on some VPNs that don't allow access to local resources while you are on them. This could be the case. We had one client VPN that no matter what we did you could not access local resources. We ended up using a VM to connect to the VPN just to avoid the headache